# document.getElementById is null with Lazysizes loaded iframe

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get the lazy loaded iframe Id and fail with a TypeError n is null. What am I missing?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var widgetIframe = document.getElementById('sclazy');
  console.log(widgetIframe);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<iframe id="sclazy" height="500" width="500" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay" class="lazyload" allowfullscreen="" data-src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/188612777&auto_play=false&buying=false&sharing=false&download=true&single_active=true&hide_related=true&show_comments=true&show_user=false&show_reposts=false&show_teaser=false&visual=true&show_artwork=true">
</iframe>
```

Comment: no idea, because there is nothing called `n` in your code, so presumably this is not the [mcve] for your _actual_ code.

Comment: The code seems to work fine for fine here.... Please create a demo reproducing your exact issue..

Comment: There is no issue in the code

Comment: Pls add some delay for this code "document.getElementById('sclazy')", call it after one sec and see if you are able to get the element.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same pb, but i did it in two times like this:

```
var iframeElement   = document.querySelector('iframe');
var iframeElementID = iframeElement.id;
```